# Bluemixのフリートライアル終了後に無料で使い続ける方法はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: bluemix

Bluemixのフリートライアル期間が終了したようで「無料アカウントからの切り替え確認」という画面が出て操作できなくなりました。テスト利用レベルであれば無料で使い続けられるという話も聞いたことがあるのですが、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
また、いままで作ったアプリは残っているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/bluemix/credit.html

これを読むと、クレジットカードを登録すれば無料枠が割り当てられて、その枠内でなら無料で使えるようです。
登録したくない、という場合はもう使えないですね。

上記URLの最後にフリートライアル終了から60日を過ぎるとアプリなどは全て削除される、とも記述があるので決断はお早めに。

Answer (score 1):

http://dotnsf.blog.jp/archives/1005257489.html

こちらのブログを見ると、無料枠の1ヶ月 375GB-Hourでどの程度使用出来るかの試算が載っていますので参考にしてみてください。

> 仮に１ヶ月を30日とすると、１ヶ月は 720 時間あります。1GB メモリのマシンを１ヶ月続けて使うと 720 時間／GB 使うことになります。これだと無料枠(375)を超えてしまいます。
>   でも（デフォルトの） **512MB メモリのマシンであれば、１ヶ月続けて使っても 360 時間／GBなので無料枠で収まることになります（１ヶ月＝31日計算でもギリギリOK）。**つまりアプリケーションサーバーのランタイムはデフォルトの 512MB メモリサーバーを１台使い続ける分には無料枠内で使える、ということだと思っています。　
>   あるいは計算上は 256MB メモリのサーバーを２台使い続けることも無料枠内でできる、とも言えます。まあ、256MB でアプリケーションサーバーがまともに動くかどうかはわかりませんが・・・